# Why do I get RuntimeError when reshaping tensor with torch.view?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to analyze FaceForensics detector [XceptionNet](https://github.com/ondyari/FaceForensics/tree/master/classification) with [this](https://github.com/moboehle/Pytorch-LRP) LRP implementation in Pytorch, but I end up stuck when trying to reshape the relevance_in tensor between the network layers.

```
def conv_nd_inverse(self, m, relevance_in):

# In case the output had been reshaped for a linear layer,
# make sure the relevance is put into the same shape as before.
relevance_in = relevance_in.view(m.out_shape)
```

m is a conv layer in the network and relevance_in is the relevance tensor received from the future layer. At relevance_in = relevance_in.view(m.out_shape) I am getting this error:

`RuntimeError: shape '[1, 2048, 10, 10]' is invalid for input of size 2048`

relevance_in has size torch.Size([1, 2048]) and m.out_shape is a list [1, 2048, 10, 10]. Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how I can solve it?

Comment: `view` tries to rearrange the tensor's elements to fit the requested shape

In your case there is no way to rearrange a tensor of 2048 elements to a tensor of 2048 * 10 * 10 elements.
What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to follow relevance from the output layer back to the input layer by backpropagating through the network. After the last conv, the tensor is flatten with x = x.view(x.size(0), -1), but as I want to follow relevance, I need the tensor to take its original shape (before flatten) when back propagating. How can I reshape it to its original shape when going backwards in the network? Which is [1, 2048, 10, 10]

Comment: Its original shape couldnt have been [1, 2048, 10, 10] if view made it into [1, 2048]. View preserves the number of elements in the original tensor.

Comment: True. Does it loose elements while passed through adaptive_avg_pool2d? The code has set "x = F.adaptive_avg_pool2d(x, (1, 1))". The last five steps are SeparableConv2d, BatchNorm2d, ReLu, adaptive_avg_pool2d, linear.

Comment: Yes, adaptive_avg_pool does reduce the size of the images, can you provide a minimal reproducible code sample so we can help you out ? :)

Comment: The LRP implementation does not support adaptive_avg_pool unfortunately so I guess that's the problem, that the values pre pooling gets lost since it doesn't save them for future analysis. I don't think any code sample will solve that. Thank you for the help! If you happen to have a link to how to implement forward hooks and back propagation through adaptive_avg_pool, let me know :)